# rails after_save callback conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a condition for a callback

```
before_save :method, :if => :email_changed? && :is_admin?
```

The method will execute even if only the second condition is true i.e `is_admin?` true.
While it works fine with lambda

```
before_save :method, :if => lambda { |u| u.email_changed? && u.is_admin? }
```

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `&&`s, `||`s or other similar operator in the bare `:if` definition because such code is **statically executed when the class itself is loaded**.

The particular statement `:if => :email_changed? && :is_admin?` is interpreted like `{ :if => :email_changed? && :is_admin? }` (it's the last parameter of the `before_save` method which can be written as a hash without the curly braces). This eventually becomes `{ :if => :is_admin? }`, see for yourself in the console:

```
{  :if => :email_changed? && :is_admin? }
# => { :if => :is_admin? }
```

The correct way to define this is indeed using a lambda so that it gets evaluated dynamically each time the callback is run.